# Azure APIM why am i getting response code of 0

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I have an APIM setup which is backed by a logic app which puts a message into a queue.
When I look in Application insights I can see non-successful requests being returned.

All I the detail I can see  get in the response code is `0 [not sent in full (see exception telemetries)]`

I have a support request open with MS around why I can query the APIM directly (which means I can't see more detail of the exception)

Under what scenarios should I expect to see a status code response of 0.

Answer (score 2):

We made an explicit decision to have [non-Http bindings](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1236#issuecomment-317846387) **return a 0 status code because they're not really Requests.** We've been talking with the App Insights team about another 'Operation'-type of Telemetry that we could use besides Request, but that's still in discussion.

For response code 0, the error code indicates that the response was empty, (as not even headers were returned). **This means the connection was accepted and then closed gracefully.** There are a number of things which could cause this, adblock, firewall, offline may cause it. A status code of 0 universally means "undefined".

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/553).